# Angular ng-repeat with bootstrap input checkbox with dynamic ng-model using ng-true-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

This problem is a little tricky for me to explain so I'll do my best. I'm trying to successfully implement Angular checkbox with their ng-true-value correctly with a dynamic ng-model.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="asset in asset">
         <h5>{{ asset.title }} categories are...{{ asset.category[0] + " and " + asset.category[1] }}</h5>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Business</label>
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="category in categoryFactory.business">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{category}}" ng-true-value="{{'category'}}" ng-model="asset.category[$index]">
                <label for="{{category}}">{{category}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Personal</label>
            <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="category in categoryFactory.personal">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{category}}" ng-true-value="{{'category'}}" ng-model="asset.category[$index]">
                <label for="{{category}}">{{category}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My end goal is when I load up my asset (find below...) it will display like the picture here [My end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJBhQ.jpg), with the correct checkboxes checked. The Business and Personal categories are derived from a factory and each form-group checkbox's are from an ng-repeat list in Business / Personal in the factory.

```
$scope.asset = [{
  title: "Sales Agreement",
  category: ["finance-admin", "running-a-business"]
}];
```

My issue is having to correctly implement ng-model inside the checkbox. Since each asset can have 1 or more category it needs to be dynamic. I have tried using $index to make my ng-model dynamic...

```
ng-model="asset.category[$index]"
```

But that seems to not work like I would have hoped. I am probably missing something very easy and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
By the way here is the
 [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pg5dqgr9/4/)

Comment: <div ng-repeat="asset in assets"> and <input type="checkbox" id="{{category}}" ng-true-value="{{category}}" ng-model="asset.category[$index]"> ??

Comment: Not sure exactly what your confused about. ng-true-value is from this ng-repeat="category in categoryFactory.business". Ng-model i'm trying to make dynamic depending on the assets categories, which in this case is category: ["finance-admin", "running-a-business"]

Comment: There is a single quote in both your ng-true-value="{{'category'}}", just wanted to point that out just incase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ng-checked, you can put function as an attribute value, ng-repeat will evaluate the function in each loop.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{category}}" ng-checked="isCategory(category)" >

$scope.isCategory = function(category){
   return  $scope.asset[0].category.indexOf(category) >= 0;
}
```

In isCategory() we are checking the indices of the category in asset.category array, if it finds it will true.

https://jsfiddle.net/pg5dqgr9/8/

Answer (score 1):

Currently as per your $index logic the two arrays `categoryFactory.business` and `asset.category` must be of same size so here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg5dqgr9/5/)

but the main part is this

First, for your case ng-true-value should be an expression

```
ng-true-value="{{category}}"
```

Second, your `asset.category` array indices should match with your options in `categoryFactory.business` array

```
$scope.asset = [{
    title: "Sales Agreement",
    category: ["", "running-a-business","",  "","finance-admin"]
}];
```

There could be a better option to manage this without relying on the $index but this should do for your case